# For loops in zsh and bash

Tags: bash, zsh

I have noticed there are two alternative ways of building loops in **zsh**:

1. `for x (1 2 3); do echo $x; done`
2. `for x in 1 2 3; do echo $x; done`

They both print:

```
1
2
3
```

My question is, why the two syntaxes?  Is `$x` iterating through a different **type of object** in each of them?

Does **bash** make a similar distinction?

### Addendum:

Why does the following work?:

```
#!/bin/zsh
a=1
b=2
c=5    

d=(a b c)    
for x in $d; do print $x;done
```

but this one doesn't?:

```
#!/bin/zsh
a=1
b=2
c=5

d=(a b c)    
# It complains with "parse error near `$d'"
for x $d; do print $x;done
```

Comment: for the example that "doesn't work", which is a *csh* style for loop, you're missing the parentheses.  `for x ($d); do print $x; done` will work, and it will match the first syntax that you have enumerated at the beginning of your question.

Comment: It is ***SO crazy*** - that those two statements - indeed do not both "work the same".  I literally can't get my head around it!  I need to smoke some of what those shell designers were smoking', back in the day, lol.

Comment: Careful, there is more to this story than initially appears. [I invite you to check my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667284/how-do-i-keep-functions-variables-local-to-my-zshrc/42081254#42081254)

Comment: I didn't see anyone else mention it, but both forms allow omission of do/done: `for i ({0..4..2}) for j ({a..c}) echo "($i,$j)"` = `{0,2,4}x{a,b,c}`. Semicolons apply to the outermost loop and redirections apply to the innermost, and if you need to change that, you only need braces: `for i ({0..4..2}) { for j ({a..c}) echo "($i,$j)" } | cat -n` = `{1,...,9}*({0,2,4}x{a,b,c})`. Of course you can combine loops with zsh expansion: `for i ("("{0..4..2}","{a..c}")") echo $i`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Several forms of complex commands such as loops have [alternate forms](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands) in zsh. These forms are mostly inspired by the [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), which was fairly common when zsh was young but has now disappeared. These alternate forms act exactly like the normal forms, they're just a different syntax. They're slightly shorter, but less clear.

The standard form for the `for` command is `for x in 1 2 3; do echo $x; done`, and the standard form for the `while` command is `while test …; do somecommand; done`. 
Ksh, bash and zsh have an alternate form of `for`: `for ((i = 0; i < 42; i++)); do somecommand; done`, which mimics the `for` loops of languages like Pascal or C, to enumerate integers. Other exotic forms that exist in zsh are specific to zsh (but often inspired by csh).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Guilles. I am still a bit confused though. Which form is the specific one to `zsh`? Also, I have added one example at the end of my OP where I can't figure out how to translate between syntaxes. If the difference is just syntax, how should I fix the second script in the addendum to make it work?

Comment: @intrpc See my updated answer. As for your last example, it doesn't work because you wrote `for x $d` and zsh expects either `in` or `(` where you wrote `$d`. Punctuation marks and reserved words can't come from a variable expansion, they have to be parsed before the shell can start on the variable expansions.

Comment: @intrpc both are zsh specific.  zsh was specifically designed to support both bourne, korn, and c-shell syntax, as it's a hybrid of all three.

Comment: For more brevity in a common case, zsh also lets you omit do ... done for  a single command: `for i in 1 2 3; echo $i`.

Comment: you can add `for i in {1..3}; do echo $i ; done` to the list of loops. (should work at least in `bash` and `zsh`)

Comment: @pseyfert It works, but it doesn't have any advantage over the forms I show: it's less portable than the `for (( … ))` form and uses a lot of memory if 3 is large.

Comment: @Gilles I was trying to `grep` through the output of a plugin using the command: `for ((i = 1; i<100; i++)); ghi show $i | grep "log"; done`. But it keeps giving me the error `zsh: parse error near `done'`. When I change the command to `for ((i = 1; i<100; i++)); ghi show $i | grep "log"`. It works fine. Any idea why? I typically try to stay in `python` but am not very familiar with `zsh` syntax...

Comment: @alpha_989 In sh-like syntax, you need `do` after `));`. Zsh also accepts another syntax `for ((…)); COMMAND` where `COMMAND` is a single command. That's why it accepts `for ((i = 1; i<100; i++)); ghi show $i | grep "log"`. When it sees `done` after this, it complains because there was no `do` to end. See [“Alternate Forms For Complex Commands” in the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands).

Answer (score 4):

In my usecase I have many font files to patch (i.e. many `.ttf` files), and I want to directly type and run the script command in Terminal (not storing it in a script file):

```
for x in JetBrainsMonoNL* ; do \
    fontforge -script fontpatcher $x --mono -l -q --fontawesome \
        --octicons --fontlogos --mdi --powerline --powerlineextra; \
done;
```

The point is: `JetBrainsMonoNL*` will be the array to loop through, and if written in the first form:

```
for x in (JetBrainsMonoNL*)
```

the parentheses look redundant (at least to me, a newbie), and I think this is why the standard is defined without them.

---

I was leanring how to create this script and found this question (based on the title), and I think this answer will be helpful for newbie people like me. You can consider this as an real life example for the accepted answer.